# How to work with Image Carousel controls jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to make a custom jQuery image carousel. i've created the `next` and `prev` button , the `next` control is working fine but the `prev`control isn't showing desired results.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ojxy3o0g/1/

i want when `current = 1` and the user clicks on the previous button the last in the image set shows i was trying

my HTML

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/img1.gif" alt="image" id="a"></li>
        <li><img src="img/img2.gif" alt="image"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider-nav">
    <button data-dir="prev">Previous</button>
    <button data-dir="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

My JS

```
(function(){


var imgLength = $('img').length;
var imgWidth  = $('img')[0].width;
var totalImageLength = imgLength * imgWidth;
var current = 1;
var currentImage = $('img');

$('button').on('click',function(){

    if($(this).data('dir') === 'next')
    {
        current++;
        currentImage.animate({
            'left':'-=600px'
        });


        if(current > imgLength)
        {
            currentImage.animate({
                'left':'0px'
            });
            current = 1;

        }
    }

    if($(this).data('dir') === 'prev'){

        current--;
        currentImage.animate({
                'left':'+=600px'
        });

        // if(current < 1)

        // }
    }

}); 


})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use imgLength:

```
    if(current < 1)
    {
        currentImage.animate({
            'left': (600 * (1 - imgLength)) + 'px'
        });
        current = imgLength;

    }
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/ojxy3o0g/4/)**

Comment: That will not work, you have to add `-` before `(600 * (imgLength - 1))`.

Comment: it's not working can you please update fiddle code ?

Comment: Oups 1 - imgLength, i fix it, better to negate the number than concat a string IMHO.